# How can I wrap a non-Traits model for use with Python Traits?

Tags: python, model-view-controller, swig, traits, enthought

I would like to wrap a non-Traits model class for use with Python Traits.  My goal is to write a Traits-based UI to manipulate an "external" model class.  The external model class has been generated by SWIG and so I cannot add enthought.traits.api.HasTraits as an ancestor (I think, though I may be wrong).

My current best attempt is

```
from enthought.traits.api import HasStrictTraits, Property, Instance

class ExternalModel():
    foo = 'foo'

class TraitsModel(HasStrictTraits):
    _e = Instance(ExternalModel)

    def __init__(self):
        self._e = ExternalModel()
        self.add_trait('foo', Property(lambda     :getattr(self._e,'foo'     ),
                                       lambda attr:setattr(self._e,'foo',attr)))
```

which causes the Traits-based class TraitsModel to have a mutable property which delegates to the contained non-Traits ExternalModel instance.  However, TraitsModel.trait_names() doesn't report 'foo' as a recognized trait.

Any suggestions for how to have TraitsModel report a 'foo' trait which is linked to ExternalModel?  enthought.traits.api.DelegatesTo seems to require the target be a Traits class (though I may not have found the right invocation and that is possible).

A more MVC-ish approach is probably to have a Traits-based view of my ExternalModel.  I've been unable to figure out having a non-Traits model for a Traits-based view.  Suggestions in that direction also greatly welcome.

**Update** I have figured out how to get HasTraits as the ExternalModel superclass using the approach at http://agentzlerich.blogspot.com/2011_05_01_archive.html and it seems to have been a complete waste of time.  Apparently the SWIG voodoo and the Traits hoodoo do not jive.  Wrapping ExternalModel within TraitsModel as this question asks seems the best route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from enthought.traits.api import HasStrictTraits, Instance, Property

class ExternalModel(object):
    foo = 'foo'

class TraitsModel(HasStrictTraits):
    _e = Instance(ExternalModel, ExternalModel())

    def __init__(self):
        '''
        >>> wrapper = TraitsModel()
        >>> wrapper.foo
        'foo'
        >>> wrapper._e.foo = 'bar'
        >>> wrapper.foo
        'bar'
        >>> wrapper.trait_names()
        ['trait_added', '_e', 'foo', 'trait_modified']
        '''
        HasStrictTraits.__init__(self)
        for trait in (name for name in dir(self._e) if not name.startswith('__')):
            self.__class__.add_class_trait(
                trait,
                Property(
                    lambda:getattr(self._e, trait),
                    lambda attr:setattr(self._e, trait, attr)
                )
            )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

A fairly robust solution is to use the [`add_class_trait`](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~jvb/ETS34_API/enthought.traits.has_traits.HasTraits.html#_add_class_trait) of the `HasTraits` class, coupled with `dir(self._e)` to get the names of the *class* attributes of `ExternalModel` and a generator expression/list comprehension to filter the magic class method names (`filter` with an appropriate function would work better for wrapping a more complex class).

Also:

- `ExternalModel` should inherit from `object`
- `__init__` should call `HasStrictTraits.__init__` (or `super(HasStrictTraits, self).__init__()`)
- `_e` can also be created in the Instance trait declaration as the second argument using `ExternalModel()` or even `()`, or as a method of TraitsModel like:

  ```
  def __e_default(self): # note preceding underscore
      return ExternalModel()
  ```

Lastly, I have an [slightly old copy of the Enthought APIs including Traits](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~jvb/ETS34_API/enthought.html) which can be very handy.

Comment: Is is possible to use this technique to `on_trait_change` on `foo`. This way, you could monitor changes in the external object. Is this possible?

Comment: The above snipped ~almost works, but on a class exported by swig, when I call wrapper.configure_traits() to open a configuration gui, the objects are just pointers to swig objects; there still needs to be some mapping there.

Comment: Also, "traits.api" module needs to be used unqualified by "enthought" these days.