# Tool for interactive exploration of function parameters

Tags: python, c++, configuration, swig, ros

Context: I am evaluating libraries for stereo correspondence. They almost universally fail to work at all until you get a handful of algorithm-dependent parameters set correctly.

Is there any sort of well-generalized tool to make the process of manually tuning tens of parameters to a badly documented C++ function until it works less painful?

I am looking for something like a combination of SWIG and the dynamic-reconfigure infrastructure from ROS, where you point it at a pure C++ function, and it generates a simple gui with sliders, check-boxes, etc... for the values of the inputs, and calls the function over-and-over so you can tune the parameters interactively.

Comment: I found "guidata" in the python ecosystem... that comes close, but you still have to manually specify which parameters you want added to the gui and their ranges, and of course you still need to write your own outer loop.

Comment: Update: reading about guidata/guiqwt, traits/traits-ui/chaco... rolling my own tool might be affordable with these libraries...

Comment: I was unable to get the windowing and graphics updating to work with guidata+matplotlib, something always seems to be locked up or not updating no matter what I do.  Will try the enthought traits/chaco stuff next...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113822/how-can-i-wrap-a-non-traits-model-for-use-with-python-traits

Comment: Update: I have come to realize that for this to be really useful, you often need to examine intermediate image values in the algorithm to understand the relationship between your 20 knobs and the final result, which demands something like a debugger plugin like the Image Watch VS pluin: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_image_watch/windows_visual_studio_image_watch.html

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like ROS's [dynamic_reconfigure](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials) with the [rqt_reconfigure](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_reconfigure) GUI might be close to what you're looking for. Once you specify the parameters you want to change, the GUI will generate sliders/toggles/fields/etc. to change the parameters on the fly:

[image]

You still need to explicitly add the mapping from a ROS param to the algorithm's parameter (and update the algorithm in the dynamic_reconfigure callback), but having your parameters stored in the ROS parameter server *can* be beneficial in the long run:

- parameters can be under version control very easily (stored as a yaml file).
- you can save all parameters once you find a good solution (`rosparam dump`)
- you can have different 'versions' of parameters for different applications.
- other nodes can read the parameters if necessary